# Vector iterators incompatible (runtime error)

Tags: c++

I am getting a runtime error saying that vector iterators incompatible.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


struct Interval
{
public:
    Interval(int s,int e):start(s),end(e) {}
    int start;
    int end;

};


void merge_intervals(vector<Interval>& Interval1, vector<Interval>& Interval2, vector<Interval>& merged)
{
    int i = 0 ;
    cout<<"i"<<i<<endl;
    vector<Interval>::iterator it1 = Interval1.begin();

    vector<Interval>::iterator it2 = Interval2.begin() ;

    while(it1 != Interval1.end() && it2 !=Interval1.end())
    {
        cout<<"i"<<i<<endl;
        i++;
        if(it1->start <= it2->start)
        {

            if(it1->end <= it2->end)
            {
                it1++;
                merged.push_back(*it1);
            }
            else
            {
                it1++;
                it2++;
                merged.push_back(Interval(it1->start,it2->end));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(it1->end >= it2->end)
            {
                it2++;
                merged.push_back(*it2);
            }
            else
            {
                it1++;
                it2++;
                merged.push_back(Interval(it2->start,it1->end));
            }
        }

        while(it1 != Interval1.end())
        {
            merged.push_back(*it1);
            *it1++;
        }

        while(it2 != Interval2.end())
        {
            merged.push_back(*it2);
            *it2++;
        }
    }
}

void print_intervals(vector<Interval>& merged)
{
    vector<Interval>::iterator  it = merged.begin();

    for(it = merged.begin();it != merged.end(); ++it)
    {
        cout<<"("<<it->start<<","<<it->end<<")"<<endl;
    }
}

void test1()
{
    vector<Interval> Interval1, Interval2, merged ;

    Interval1.push_back(Interval(1,4));
    Interval1.push_back(Interval(6,10));
    Interval1.push_back(Interval(14,19));

    Interval2.push_back(Interval(13,17));

    merge_intervals(Interval1, Interval2, merged);
    print_intervals(merged);

}

int main()
{
    test1();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does this have to do with `interview-questions`?

Answer (score 4):

`it2 !=Interval1.end()` compares an iterator from `Interval2` to an iterator from `Interval1` – this is illegal.

Assuming that was just a typo, simply correct it to `it2 != Interval2.end()`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Its my bad I am unable to find a simple mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You compare `it2` with `Interval1.end()`:

```
while(it1 != Interval1.end() && it2 !=Interval1.end())
```

There should be:

```
while(it1 != Interval1.end() && it2 !=Interval2.end())
```